# Dictionary inside array loop

Tags: python, arrays, django, dictionary

Given a json file with the following data:

```
[
    {
        "activityId": "Task_5.1.1",
        "activityInstanceId": "Task_5.1.1:8c42f564-cdbe-11ea-8be8-00155d891509",
        "errorMessage": null,
        "errorDetails": null,
        "executionId": "8c42ce53-cdbe-11ea-8be8-00155d891509",
        "id": "8c431c75-cdbe-11ea-8be8-00155d891509",
        "lockExpirationTime": null,
        "processDefinitionId": "Process_5.1.1:1:d1c02af8-cdb8-11ea-8be8-00155d891509",
        "processDefinitionKey": "Process_5.1.1",
        "processInstanceId": "8c42802b-cdbe-11ea-8be8-00155d891509",
        "retries": null,
        "suspended": false,
        "workerId": null,
        "topicName": "AppointIM",
        "tenantId": null,
        "priority": 0,
        "businessKey": "57a4c7e9-fd9f-4d71-a39d-7bd8e112a39a"
    },
    {
        "activityId": "Task_5.1.1",
        "activityInstanceId": "Task_5.1.1:fcad6582-cdb8-11ea-8be8-00155d891509",
        "errorMessage": null,
        "errorDetails": null,
        "executionId": "fcad6581-cdb8-11ea-8be8-00155d891509",
        "id": "fcad6583-cdb8-11ea-8be8-00155d891509",
        "lockExpirationTime": null,
        "processDefinitionId": "Process_5.1.1:1:d1c02af8-cdb8-11ea-8be8-00155d891509",
        "processDefinitionKey": "Process_5.1.1",
        "processInstanceId": "fcacf049-cdb8-11ea-8be8-00155d891509",
        "retries": null,
        "suspended": false,
        "workerId": null,
        "topicName": "AppointIM",
        "tenantId": null,
        "priority": 0,
        "businessKey": "f254eb9e-93a5-48e0-8a8e-a95c9fd17ab3"
    }
]
```

I am trying to only save the dictionaries where businessKey is equal to some value. This will then be display in a template.

i can access each item using: `items_display = list_task['tasks'][0]`

but there can sometimes be as many as 1000 sets or as few as 0.

I need a method of first searching for all dicts that have the required value: and either discard the remainder or secondly save the found items to a new dict that can be accessed in the template.

I have been failing for over 4 hours trying different methods etc:

I can get the key : values etc by using the index as above but need a method to iterate through all the possible number of indexes.

Comment: A simple list comprehension will give you a new list with just the items that meet your condition: `filtered = [item for item in MyList if item['businessKey'] == someValue]`

Comment: i tried that and got "string indices must be integers" list_task = get_tasks()
    filtered = [item for item in list_task if item['businessKey'] == pk]

Comment: pk is a UUID if that helps?

Comment: the list_task format is list_task{'tasks': [{ k:v, k:v}{k,v}{etc, etc}]}

Comment: If your list is inside the a dictionary under the key `tasks`, then you need to pass that to the list comprehension.

Comment: list_task = get_tasks() # returns tasks[{}{}]
    MyList = list_task['tasks']
    filtered = [item for item in MyList if item['businessKey'] == str(pk)]

Comment: @MarkMeyer how would a query to have contains be made e.g. instead of == would be contains"some text"?

Comment: @DjanoStarter `if 'substring' in some_string`